# Routes and regex in Kohana 3.0

Tags: php, url-routing, kohana

New to Kohana... I was wondering if it's possible to use regex for setting up a route that handles all requests except for one, 'main_page' for example?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you dont need a regex to do that. its like you would do it in the .htaccess

```
Route::set('main_page', 'main_page(/<action>(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller'    => 'main_page',
        'action'        => 'some_action',
    ));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'welcome',

    ));
```

Comment: You can't have a slash at the beginning of a route. Otherwise, this is a perfect example.